# Remove cookies from jquery ajax calls

Tags: session, jquery

I would do jquery ajax calls discarding every cookie, so I can have a new session for every call.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: you mean : the cookies you've set ? you could build a function to do it and call it within your ajax call ? i don't really understand the point though.

Comment: I mean in particular the session cookie. I want to be able to make ajax calls discarding the current session. 

So I would do whatever it takes for deleting or ignoring the session cookie that would be posted in the ajax request. Does it makes more sense? Please, let me know.

Comment: @Harun @JMax   I have to do this for testing purposes, so I do not care very much about the current session.

Comment: ok, that's not for production purposes :). Glad the solution we gave answers your question

Comment: I know this is now offtopic but, wouldn't a valid production use for this be to enable heavy caching on certain requests without having to set up special rules in varnish (for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Harun pointed out, maybe you should consider a wider solution than deleting a session cookie that will **alter the whole user session** and not only your AJAX call.

To litteraly answer your question, you could delete the cookie you've set (provided you've set by yourself and not by another framework):

```
$.cookie("session", null);
$.ajax( url, [settings] )
```

But, that's **probably not the good solution** because you will delete the whole user session at each ajax call. You should tell us more about what you are doing so that we could help you.

Comment: Doing it in JavaScript is a bad idea because it won't be guaranteed to clear by the server. Maybe using JS as a fallback layer is okay, but the server should be deleting the cookie.

Comment: A lot of times when you're doing this kind of thing, it's because you have an adversarial relationship with the server.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX request is exactly an HTTP request (XMLHTTPRequest). Cookies get sent back and forth in the AJAX request-response headers in order to maintain the state of user session across multiple HTTP requests.

HTTP is an inherently stateless protocol and hence cookies are used to maintain the state of user's session across multiple HTTP requests.

Instead of removing cookies host all your static components(like images) in a Cookie-free Domain. The following url might might give you some info in this,

http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/

Comment: This is totally the right answer. I don't know why the other one is at the top!